# Change Marker dynamically based on if condition in animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I have a list of points; after I convert it to an array, I want to display the point with the marker 'o', but if the distance between the point and a mobile point is more than 10, for example, the marker of the point should change from 'o' to '*'. I trid to do this, but all the marker points changed not just the markers that satisfy the `if` condition.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
def createList(r1, r2):
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2+1)]

r1, r2 = 1, 50
mialistax=createList(r1, r2)
mialistay=createList(r1, r2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

import numpy as np
x_l=np.array(mialistax)
y_l = np.array(mialistay)

def animate(i):

    max_x= max(mialistax)
    max_y=max(mialistay)
    ax.clear()

    if (x_l[i]>10):
        mark='*'
    else:
        mark='o'

    ax.plot(x_l[i],y_l[i],marker=mark)
    ax.set_xlim([0,max_x])
    ax.set_ylim([0,max_y])
    plt.plot(x_l,y_l,marker=mark)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=500, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

In this code, the marker changes for all the points, but I want that the marker changed for only the points that satisfy the `if` condition.

Comment: You don't need the `python-3.x` tag for this question, so it can be removed. The `python` tag is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want an animation that shows all the points, but the point at index `i`, which is the frame number, should be converted to a `"*"` marker if its `x` value is greater than 10.

To start, you have three issues. The first is the order of your plots.

```py
ax.plot(x_l[i], y_l[i], marker=mark)
ax.plot(x_l, y_l, marker=mark)
```

This means that you first plot your individual point and then the rest of the points on top. So you won't see your "special" point because it is covered up by the other points.

The second issue is that you're setting the same marker for both of the plots (the individual point and the rest of them). I would create a list of all the markers and update the marker at index `i` if it meets the condition. Then, loop through all the points and plot them individually (since you cannot pass a marker list). You probably want to have your "special" point stand out, so we can show it as a different color.

```py
markers = ["o"]*len(x_l)

def animate(i):
    max_x = max(x_l)
    max_y = max(y_l)
    ax.clear()

    if x_l[i] > 10:
        markers[i] = '*'

    ax.set_xlim([0, max_x])
    ax.set_ylim([0, max_y])
    
    for indx, (x, y, marker) in enumerate(zip(x_l, y_l, markers)):
        color = "tab:orange" if indx == i else "tab:blue"
        ax.plot(x, y, marker=marker, color=color)
```

Lastly, you only have 50 points, but have `frames=200`, so you need to either increase your points or decrease the number of frames to match.

```py
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(x_l), interval=5, repeat=False)
```

[image]

---

I assume you're new to Python, so I'll also make other suggestions to improve your code.

1. You can directly create a list from a `range` by using the `list` function: `list(range(start, stop))`. Since you are converting it to a numpy array, there is a numpy function for this: `np.arange(start, stop)`.
2. With numpy arrays you can use the `max` method: `x_l.max()`, though this change isn't as important.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.close("all")


r1 = 1
r2 = 50
x_l = np.arange(r1, r2+1)
y_l = np.arange(r1, r2+1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

markers = ["o"]*x_l.shape[0]

def animate(i):
    max_x = x_l.max()
    max_y = y_l.max()
    ax.cla()
    
    if x_l[i] > 10:
        markers[i] = '*'
    
    for indx, (x, y, marker) in enumerate(zip(x_l, y_l, markers)):
        color = "tab:orange" if indx == i else "tab:blue"
        ax.plot(x, y, marker=marker, color=color)
        
    ax.set_xlim([0, max_x])
    ax.set_ylim([0, max_y])


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=x_l.shape[0], interval=500, repeat=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for all the advices, now i know better what to do but i want that the point that are more than 10 remain in marker='*' not return to marker 'o' and the point before 10 stay in marker 'o'.

Comment: That can be done, but then I am not sure what that animation is. What changes between each frame?

Comment: Between each frame have to change the marker type, like if x>10 than the marker change and remain with this marker type: '*'

Comment: I'm aware that English is not your first language, so it is difficult to understand what you want. `x_l[i]` returns the `x` value at the index equal to the frame number, `i`. If you want all the points where `x > 10` to have the marker `"*"`, then that is a static image. I do not see what you want to change between each frame of the animation.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sorry for my english, i try to explain, when the condition x_l[i]>10 the point change the marker and remain in this state with " * " marker, i know this can be done by a static image with a scatter plot but i want an animation that change the marker and after remain in the new marker from 'o' to " * " but only the points under the condition and remain with the new marker.

Comment: If the frames=50 like the dimension of the x_list, in everyframe i assume that if the condition is true than change the marker type from 'o' to ' * ' and remain with this new marker to the end of the frames, else not change the marker and remain 'o'

Comment: @FrancescoRossi I have updated my answer. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i want, thank you for your help!

Comment: Great. In the future, you don't need to thank someone in the comments. Comments are meant for clarification and questions. Instead, you should accept the answer (click the gray check next to the question to make it a green check) and upvote an answer (once you have enough reputation).

Comment: Perfect, i'm also new here and i already upvate the answer.

Comment: Upvoting is different than accepting an answer. When you ask a question, you can accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you set frame to an integer, for example as you did `frames=200`, then `range(200)` will be passed to `animate()` function and your parameter for `animate(i)`, is considered as an integer inside your function definition and not a range object. Instead you can set an iterating object, like python list or numpy array for frame argument. Please run below code to get an idea for frame argument:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
def createList(r1, r2):
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2+1)]

r1, r2 = 1, 50
mialistax=createList(r1, r2)
mialistay=createList(r1, r2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

import numpy as np
x_l=np.array(mialistax)
y_l = np.array(mialistay)

def animate(i):

    max_x= max(mialistax)
    max_y=max(mialistay)
    ax.clear()

    if (x_l[i]>10):
        mark='*'
    else:
        mark='o'

    ax.plot(x_l[i],y_l[i],marker=mark)
    ax.set_xlim([0,max_x])
    ax.set_ylim([0,max_y])
    plt.plot(x_l,y_l,marker=mark)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=[5,15], interval=500, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry but it's doesn't help me, it seems that tha point just move faster.

Comment: I made repeat=True and interval is 500 which is half second. There are 2 value in frames: 5 and 15. One is less than 10 and one more than 10. As repeat is True, for every half second frame changes from 5 to 15 that causes marker to change from 'o' to '*'.